# How much more data does my classifier need?

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset of ~100k news articles, and I'm trying to build a classifier based on the headlines and leads of every article. The dataset is not pre-labeled so I'm manually labelling a subset of the articles to train on. So far, I have 9 categories with ~600 labeled articles for each category. I'm using `doc2vec` to create document vectors and the `SVC` classifier from `sklearn` to make predictions.

My cross validation score (with 10 splits and shuffling of data) is hovering around 0.89.

When I plot a learning curve for the training set and test set, I interpret it as the classifier suffering from high variance, and that I need to collect more data. But is there any way I can approximate how much more data is needed to get a cross validation score of say, 0.95?

Here is my learning curve and the mean scores:

[image]

Training scores: 1.0, 0.99919679, 0.9991984 , 0.99791667, 0.99615385, 0.99550155, 0.99487179.

Testing scores: 0.40769912, 0.72283119, 0.78529511, 0.83461723, 0.85527486, 0.86151579, 0.86471912.

**EDIT**: I performed a grid search on the C and gamma parameters to the SVC model, and adjusted gamma to 0.015 which made the two lines converge a bit more. Adding plot and new scores.

[image: Learning curve after adjusting gamme]

New training scores: 0.97758621, 0.98703072, 0.98177172, 0.97540872, 0.96717739, 0.96479244, 0.96241702.

New testing scores: 0.45800254, 0.78917394, 0.83526468, 0.853326, 0.86849859, 0.87232875, 0.87508134.

Comment: Now you have high variance problem, you have to employ generalization techniques, if you are using SVM, you can change the lambda hyper-parameter. You have to tune it to find a model to generalize well. I guess your data is enough based on the reported accuracy.

Comment: What is the horizontal axis?

Comment: Can you label the red and green lines?

Comment: I've added axes labels and a legend.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have enough data. Your problem seems to be one of generalization, which is in general a tricky one to solve.
For SVM, depending on what kind you have, you could try tinkering with the parameters and kernels.
Have a look here. -- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35276/svm-overfitting-curse-of-dimensionality?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa